# wordpress: creating a conditional statement to load featured image if it exists else a default image

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I've searched for similar questions to mine here, but haven't found a thread that helps me.. although I did find help here to get to the point where I am now ;)

I've created a jquery slideshow that pulls images from the featured images in a certain post category. I found the code below here at SO and got it to work to my needs so far, but I'd need to add a conditional statement to it:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
$showImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post->ID ), 'xiao-show-img' );
} ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" rel="<?php the_excerpt() ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $showImg[0]; ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" rel="<?php the_excerpt() ?>" />
</a>
```

that works ok, but.. i'd like to use something like below to be able to load a default image into the slideshow, if there is no featured image attached to the post:

```
<?php
if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" rel="<?php the_excerpt() ?>">
        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" rel="<?php the_excerpt() ?>" />
    </a> 
 <?php
    } else { 
 ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" rel="<?php the_excerpt() ?>">
        <img src="<?php get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/xiao-default-image.png" />;
            </a>
    <?php }
 ?>
```

I realise that the below example doesn't work.

Comment: Why does your example not work? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: hi Adam, thanks for checking in so quickly. I don't know why the bottom example doesn't work. I was hoping it would and simply need a nudge in the right direction to get it to work or if I'm thinking completely wrong in doing it that way. I just saw that I had left out a closing anchor tag, but that isn't the culprit.

Comment: It seems fine to me, what error, if any, are you actually getting here when you try to run this code, which image is rendered?

Comment: the page loads, but not the images. none of the sizes of the images are being read by the slideshow code etc.. while if i use the above code ti works fine, only that I don't have the option of the default image being loaded if there is no featured image attached to the post. thanks for looking at this... really not sure why the below doesn't work.. i was hoping there would be something obvious wrong with it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main culprit in your code is `src="<?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>"`

as the_post_thumbnail() will echo out the html needed for the entire image tag so try this instead...

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
    </a> 
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>">
        <img src="<?php get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/xiao-default-image.png" />;
    </a>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Adam, great thanks that makes so much sense! ;) it completely works, but there is a little snag now... part of the cause that I ended up with the faulty code is that my jQuery code is functioning by getting the <img> element from the loaded image and based on that loading switching to next image etc... is there away around this? can i load the values into variables somehow?

Comment: Adam, never mind I got over my panic and modified the jQuery code (not entirely confident there either to say the least).. all working like I was hoping now! thanks for your speedy help!! cheers. david

Comment: for anyone wanting to use this I should add that I had to put 'echo' back just before the 'get_bloginfo()' to get it to print the image to screen... i guess it got missing while i was troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

Easier method - just change the style of that image to include `background-image: url('images/xiao=default-image.png');` with a properly set `width:` and `height:`. Then you don't need the `if/else` statement, but also change your `$showImg` to include the `src`, and give your image a custom class:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
   $showImg = 'src="' . wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post->ID ), 'xiao-show-img' ) . '"';
} ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" rel="<?php the_excerpt() ?>">
    <img class="usedefault" <?php echo $showImg[0]; ?> title="<?php the_title() ?>" rel="<?php the_excerpt() ?>" />
</a>
```

Your style would be something like...

```
.usedefault {
    background-image: etc...
}
```

Comment: Matt thanks for taking the time. i completely understand what you're doing, but the default bg  does seem like it's over-riding the post_thumbnail.. i only get an empty div at the height/width i set in css... i might be a bit dim at the moment though.. however I would like to get the conditional statement working just to finish off what i started.. thanks again or taking the time